# Why was the question "International vehicle registration sticker" Put On Hold?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

Why was the question [International vehicle registration sticker](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/122282/international-vehicle-registration-sticker) put On Hold as being related to emigrating (Expat Stack Exchange)?

While it's true that the OP was emigrating to the Czech Republic (it was only mentioned in the comments). The scope of the question related only to whether it was a legal requirement for a Canadian automobile to display an Oval CDN sticker while visiting Europe.

The use of an oval country sticker is only a temporary measure and is not permitted for long term use of cars anyway (If you use a foreign car for more than a year in the Czech republic you have to register it).

While I admit, shipping a car from Canada to Europe is a lot of effort for a short trip, I've seen it done.

Comment: Since you say that emigration is out of scope of the question, would a suggestion to rent a car constitute a valid answer?

Answer (score 4):

I agree with you that as the question stands, it's on topic and we have similar questions on our site. I voted to reopen.

Answer (score -3):

I didn't vote to close the question but it looks like OP is interested on registration procedures for a permanent import of the car to the EU. Those would be quite different from any temporary import permits.

Comment: There is no mention of any registration procedures in the question, the only thing being asked is in relation to the requirement for a sticker.

Answer (score -6):

The question is about bringing a car from Canada to Europe. Even just getting the car across the ocean is such a monumental pain in the butt that only somebody who was emigrating would try.

Comment: I did the Mongol rally and I saw several teams ship their vehicles across the Atlantic to the start line. None of them were emigrating

Comment: That's something of a special case, and I'm sure the asker would have mentioned it if they had something like that in mind.

Comment: The answer of the question is not exclusively for the benefit of the asker but for the benefit of the community. In the same way if I was asking about taking my dog overseas with me, it doesn't matter if I'm asking because I'm planning to emigrate or just go on vacation with my pet, the point is there's an answer to a specific query which relates to travel. The fact that it also relates to immigration shouldn't matter.